# On completed $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having troubles with what seems to be a very simple problem, but I just cannot get my head around formalizing it. Here it is.

- Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measured space.
- Let $\mathcal{N}_\mu$ the set of all the null sets ($N\in X$ is a null set if $\exists A\in\mathcal{A} | \mu(A) = 0, N\subset A$).
- Let $\overline{A}^\mu := \{A\cup N | A\in\mathcal{A}, N \in \mathcal{N}_\mu\}$

Prove that $\overline{A}^\mu$ contains $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{N}_\mu$, then prove that any $\sigma$-algebra containing those two sets contains $\overline{A}^\mu$.

The first part of the problem seems obvious, but I cannot write it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $A=\emptyset $ and $N=\emptyset $ respectively.

Comment: From that I conclude $\emptyset \in \overline{A}^\mu$, but I don't know where to go after. Also, I know that $\overline{A}^\mu = \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}_\mu)$ and that it would solve the problem. But I can't use that because the last question of the exercise consists in concluding that $\overline{A}^\mu = \sigma(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{N}_\mu)$.

Comment: @8827 setting $A=\emptyset$ yields $\mathcal N_\mu \subset \overline{A}^\mu$. setting $N=\emptyset$ yields $\mathcal A \subset \overline{A}^\mu$.

Comment: God I'm so stupid. Thank you.